# 2D Colorplot python with missing values

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have data in the following format:

```
x = [23.0757 23.8643 24.6545 25.4138 27.7498 28.5586 29.3396 30.079 30.8425 31.6162 32.3812]
y = [11.3574 11.1981 11.0303 10.8517 10.2982 10.1016 9.8989 9.7036 9.4833 9.2579 9.0362]
z = [15.1817 15.0578 13.9388 12.8876 13.0838 12.1634 10.6768 9.6899 9.712 9.8358 9.5188]
```

I would like to plot a 2D colorplot to replicate following picture (without the black lines and arrows):

[image]

I do want to keep the holes (if the x distance between two values is greater than 2, there should be a hole) in the picture and do not want to interpolate the data between them. I just managed to to a 2D plot of the x and y with z as colormap, but I do want to have a smooth surface with the color and not just the dots.

```
fig = plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x,y,s=80,c=z,cmap='jet') 
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

Can somebody give me some tips on how to achieve this?

Comment: You are probably looking for a [contourf plot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/plot_types/arrays/contourf.html#sphx-glr-plot-types-arrays-contourf-py), however for such a plot [Z has to be 2D](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.contourf) (and not 1D as in your z). That means there needs to be a z value for every x,y (area) point, and right now there is only a 'line' (1D) of z and not an area. You may want to check your data source if that can be provided in your question.

Comment: I have 1760x, y and z points. I think I can convert the x and y data with mesh grid to get the area, but is there a way to convert the z data to match the mesh grid? But I think it isn't possible because the x and y is not regularly spaced. Unfortunately I can't get more data...

Comment: your amount of z values needs to be x amount *  y amount. If your data doesn't represent that such a contour plot just makes no sense in the 1st place.

Comment: You can likely interpolate onto a regular grid and set the holes to NaN. In short, it sounds like you'll have to generate the image yourself.